# "Attempted relative import in non-package" on Google Cloud ML

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Since yesterday or the day before, I get a

`ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

for an import in my main trainer file like

`from . import mobilenet_v1 as mobilenet`

when running the exact same trainer code with the exact same parameters on cloud ML using the exact same training job. I'm bundling my trainer using the `gcloud` tool. I tried rolling my own `setup.py` instead without luck. Any pointers as to what this could be caused by?

Comment: This might be a bug being rolled out. We will investigate.

Comment: Can you verify the date of your last successful run?

Comment: Oct 14, 2017, 8:42:27 AM (pacific time, I believe)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. For what it's worth, I had set up my stuff to follow the style guidelines [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/style_guide) with absolute import. As such my import statements have to look like the above. It seems like you're not doing that in the samples, e.g. [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was *actually* a Cloud ML bug. It has been fixed! Thank you for the super fast turnaround.

Comment: Hi Catalin, we are investigating the root cause of the issue. Can you please provide your module structure and the module name that's passed to gcloud? It would be also helpful if you can send us the project number and job id via cloudml-feedback@google.com. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Sure! Will do. Thank you!